# Diagram in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, tikz-arrows, technical-drawing

I've been trying to replicate this image

[image: Fluid Limits]

, using TIKZ, but so far the results have been very bad.

I'd like to know with you have tips/hints on how I should do it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  >={Straight Barb[angle=30:2pt 8]},
myarrow/.style={
  decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{Straight Barb[angle=30:1pt 4]}};
    },
  postaction=decorate  
  }
]
\draw[->]
  (0,0) -- (8,0);
\draw[->]
  (0,0) -- (0,8);

\draw[->]
  (0,6) -- ++(0,1) node[left] {$\lambda_{v}$};
\draw[->]
  (0,6) -- ++(0,-1) node[left] {$\mu_{v}$};  
\draw[->]
  (0,6) -- ++(1,0) node[right] {$\lambda_{1}$};  

\draw[->]
  (6,0) -- ++(1,0) node[below] {$\lambda_{h}$};
\draw[->]
  (6,0) -- ++(-1,0) node[below] {$\mu_{h}$};  
\draw[->]
  (6,0) -- ++(0,1) node[above] {$\lambda_{2}$};  

\draw[line width=1pt,myarrow]
  (4,0) -- (0,0);
\draw[line width=1pt,myarrow]
  (2.5,3) -- (4,0);

\draw[dashed,->]
  (2.5,3) -- ++(1,0) node[above right] {$\lambda_{1}-\mu_{1}$};  
\draw[dashed,->]
  (2.5,3) -- ++(0,-1) node[left] {$\lambda_{2}-\mu_{2}$};  

\draw[->]
  (0,0) -- (0,1) node[right] (l0) {$-\lambda_{0}$};
\node[below] at (l0|-0,0) {$\phantom{-}\lambda_{0}$};

\draw[<->]
  (4,5) node[left] {$\mu_{1}$} -- (6,5) node[right] {$\lambda_{1}$};
\draw[<->]
  (5,4) node[below] {$\mu_{2}$} -- (5,6) node[above] {$\lambda_{2}$};

\draw[->,dashed]
  ([yshift=7pt]2.75,0) -- node[above] {$\nu_{\pi}$} ++(-1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Uauh, it looks SUPER GOOD! Thank you very much, @gonzalo-medina.

Comment: @GuilhermeThompson You're welcome!